# How to enable multi-selecting in ASP.NET CheckBoxList control?

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I've been struggling with this, is there a way to do it using just configuration?
Do I necessarily have to handle multi-selection manually, with post-backs?

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="uxVisibilityScopeCheckBoxList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
```

This definition only allows 1 checkbox to be selected.

Thanks!

### EDIT:

Turns out we had a **jscript** somewhere deep, that was hooking to all of the **input[type=checkbox]** controls, and allowing to select only 1 checkbox of a same group.

Gotta be careful with those.

Comment: What?? A checkbox list is intended for multiple selection. You can always select more that one option when have multiple options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:CheckBoxList id="check1" AutoPostBack="false"
TextAlign="Right" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Also look at this link

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_checkboxlist

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static Dictionary<int, string> ListDayWeek()
    {
        var days = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        days.Add(1, "Monday");
        days.Add(2, "Tuesday");
        days.Add(3, "Wednesday");
        days.Add(4, "Thursday");
        days.Add(5, "Friday");
        return days;
    }

       DropDownItem.DataSource = GlobalVar.ListItem();
       DropDownItem.DataValueField = "Key";
       DropDownItem.DataTextField = "Value";
       DropDownItem.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="uxVisibilityScopeCheckBoxList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Mercury</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Venus</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we had a **jscript** somewhere deep, that was hooking to all of the **input[type=checkbox]** controls, and allowing to select only 1 checkbox of a same group.

Gotta be careful with those.