# show asp.net checkbox list items in different cells of html table

Tags: c#, asp.net

As described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836540/how-to-enable-multi-selecting-in-asp-net-checkboxlist-control)
 link , I can create checkbox list in a asp.net webform page .

I want to display each listItem in different Row of html table , As the user will select some files which are being displayed in Different Rows . Each row has a checkbox with it . The user can select multiple files being displayed in multiple Rows .How can I acheive this ?

Here is my code which need to be replaced with asp:Checkbox:

```
<td valign=bottom align='center'  bgcolor='#DA8191'>
<input type='checkBox' name=chkOnline value='abc'>
<td>
```

The above code is placed in a loop , so the number of checkbox list items depends upon the file incoming from database .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question could do with some fleshing out.

As you are using asp.net, I imagine you are also using MVC. so when you say file, i imagine it's whatever your controller is passing to the view. In this case, you must iterate over your model. So, I imagine you need something like:

```
@model ...

...

@foreach (var s in Model){
<tr>
  <td valign=bottom align='center'  bgcolor='#DA8191'>
    <input type='checkBox' name=chkOnline value='abc'>
  </td>
</tr>
}

...
```

then you can access any properties on the Model within the for, and thus generate your checkboxes as you wish.

Comment: The fact that he mentions the `asp:Checkbox` tag and `asp.net webform page` suggests he's using asp.net web forms.

Comment: No , i'm not using MVC

Answer (score 1):

You can fill a CheckBoxList from code behind with the values from a database or other source.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Code behind:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Insert(i, new ListItem("Value " + (i + 1), i.ToString(), true));
}
```

Or with a reader:

```
int i = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Insert(i, new ListItem(reader["ColumnA"].ToString(), reader["ColumB"].ToString(), true));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I want to bind each check box at specific <td> under html . How could i do this by using code behind

Comment: Then it's easier to use separate CheckBox Controls, not a CheckBoxList.